# Загрузка файла на локальный сервер с помощью PHP

Tags: php

Только изучаю PHP, не судите стого :)
Сделал простую форму:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>Форма для загрузки файлов на сервер и отправки на почту</p>
        <p>Выберите картинки <input type="file" name="fl"></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Загрузить на сервер">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

И обработчик на PHP:

```
<?php
    // Каталог, в который мы будем принимать файл:
$uploaddir = '%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);

// Копируем файл из каталога для временного хранения файлов:
if (copy($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
{
echo "<h3>Файл успешно загружен на сервер</h3>";
}
else { echo "<h3>Ошибка! Не удалось загрузить файл на сервер!</h3>"; exit; }
?>
```

Вот кусок php.ini, который отвечает за файлы:

```
file_uploads = On
upload_tmp_dir = "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/"
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M 
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Однако, когда я пытаюсь загрузить файл - получаю ошибку:
Warning: copy(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\upload.php on line 7

Сижу, ломаю голову, в чем проблема... Прошу помощи в решении данной проблемы...

З.Ы. Сервер OpenServer

Comment: Вместо copy() используйте move_uploaded_file().

Comment: @Alexander Zonov это просто рекоммендация или решение проблемы? :)

Comment: Это рекомендация как вариант решения проблемы.......а вообще мне кажется должно быть еще `$_FILES['fl']` а не `$_FILES['uploadfile']` ибо откуда оно у вас взялось?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский понял, буду пробовать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, затупил, поставил 'fl'. Но выскочила другая ошибка Warning: copy(%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/4.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\upload.php on line 7

Я так понял, что теперь проблема с путями к месту, куда файл должен загружаться...

Comment: всё может быть... для начала заменить копи на move_uploaded_file как писали выше.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нужно просто поменять название функции, параметры остаются те же?

Comment: @Dremjke да. но вообще всегда можно в доках глянуть http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php  когда не знаешь или не помнишь что-то

Comment: @АлексейШиманский получае такое:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\upload.php on line 7

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\php8B9E.tmp' to '%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/1.jpg' in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\upload.php on line 7

у меня закрадываются подозрения, что проблема  директории, куда хочу загрузить. Или путь не правильно указываю, или на директорию нет прав на запись...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В общем, спасибо за инфу и за ссылку, буду по ней пробоать делать)

Comment: Вы попробуйте человеческий путь указать, без процентов. Типа /var/www/uploads/ . Вот тут хороший пример http://www.php.su/phphttp/?uploads

Comment: @Dremjke, вы хотите скопировать/переместить файл по в '%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/1.jpg'. Папки %sprogdir% не существует. Вы ожидаете, что %sprogdir% это подстановка, но это не так.

Comment: @Dremjke так ты пытаешься залить файл в temp папку ...и то даже не в неё))........`%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/` в настройках php.ini  указаны и сервер может с этим разобраться..... а вот вторым параметром надо указать абсолютный или относительный путь до папки без всяких процентов.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov точно, я и не подумал... Только фишка в том, что у меня винда) Как правильно написать путь? Этот с процентами я просто скопировал с php.ini... мне нужно указать полный путь, как он указывается в винде? к примеру C:\OpenServer\userdata\temp

Comment: Чтобы узнать путь в OpenServer: - вывести меню -> Дополнительно - > Информация PHP. Винда тут ни при чем, это связано с Апачем.

Comment: @labris всё, разорбрался :) Указал правильно полный путь и файлы теперь успешно загружает!)

Comment: Господа, всем спасибо за отклики, всем очень благодарен! Вы помогли мне решить проблему)